# VLOOKUP assistance: match column with column on another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have a fairly simple `VLOOKUP` Question but I'm comically horrible with Excel.

Basically, I have two spreadsheets.  I'm wanting to find data from Column B of Sheet 2 on Column W from Sheet 1.  If the data is an exact match, I would like for it to show "True"

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The question you want to ask Excel of every cell in column W in sheet 1 "is there an exactly equal entry in column B of sheet 2". Correct?

Comment: Can you show example data and what formulas you tried?  It's easier for us to help with a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you, you are looking for a formula similar to this one:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1,SHEET2!W:W,1,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE)
```

You should apply it in Sheet 1. Note that it only covers cell B1, you can now apply it to any other cell by changing that first argument.